# How to read database information from local file vb.net

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I have a program written in Visual Basic that connects to a mysql server for editing.  I am going to test it in real time through a local company, but is there a way to make the program read the database connection info through a local file? (Maybe a .txt)...  I don't want the company to have to edit the entire program to update their connection information.  Is this possible, or what is a better alternative?

Comment: Add `app.config` to your app. There you can have your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the database in mysql (perhaps name it TEST DB), and connect to that database in your vb.net Application.
At end of the test and when you don't need said database anymore, drop the database then.

Other than this, you can install MYSQL locally on the client's computer, back up your db there, connect vb.net, then do the test.

I would prefer the former solution though.

Comment: The idea is to make it so the company does not have to edit the vb project, but can input the database connection info from a file on the desktop, etc. Incase they change database passwords or something, then obviously the program couldn't connect without editing the source code

Comment: Then duplicate the database. Backup the source, Let them test on it, then after the test, drop the database on the server and backup.